# React Native - get data from Promise

Tags: react-native, promise

in my React Native app I receive a token from an API. Everytime the app sends a request to the server this token is needed. I save the token in the AsyncStorage:

```
export const onSignIn = (value) =>  AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_TOKEN', value);
```

In many different parts of the app I need this token and therefore I wanted to use a function, that extracts the information out of the token:

```
export const getTokenInfo = async () => {
    try{
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN')
        .then((res) => {
          const jsonData = jwtDecode(res);
          return jsonData;
        })
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('caught error', e);
    }
}
```

When calling the function in other Components it just returns the Promise itself and not the token. Is there a possibility to get the token, but not the promise? A possible approach was to use `setState()` to store the token in a state, but there are some components like DrawerNavigator that are not in a class.

Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Use cookies instead.

Comment: I'm little confused with your code. AsyncStorage.getItem() return a string. Why are you converting into json?

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to return the value on your getTokeninfo function

```js
export const getTokenInfo = async () => {
    try{
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN')
        .then((res) => {
          const jsonData = jwtDecode(res);
          return jsonData;
        })
        
        return value // <---- you forgot this line
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('caught error', e);
    }
}
```